# The meaning of (nani ga) 何が + N (something) + なんですか (nan desuka) in this context

Tags: grammar, meaning, expressions, japanese-to-english

**I can only guess the meaning like :"What do you mean by mentions N here ?" but I'm not sure
Hope someone can help me understand its correct meaning.**

Context: MC is trying to learn cooking in order to reopen a restaurant for a friend (he's also worked there before, but only as a waiter) .And then 1 of his other friend (A) asked him about this.

A「そういえば、Bはお店を再開しようとしているのであろう」

B (MC)「あ、うん……そうなんだ」

A「いつだ。いつからだ。大盛りか」

**MC「何が大盛りなんですかっ」**

MC「Mさんがほとんど仕切ってたけど、その仕事を今調べてて……中々大変です」(M-san is the previous manager of the restaurant, she did most of the cooking parts for the restaurant. But now she's gone, and MC is trying to learn from a notebook that M-san had left behind.)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably it points to the fact that there is something absurd about the previous utterance, particularly around 大盛り. However, what is absurd is difficult to tell from the given context (and frankly, I think that's more of a story comprehension issue than a language issue, so I'm not sure if additional context will be helpful here without going off-topic.)

Answer (score 0):

It's similar to something like:

A: Hey, this photograph looks beautiful.

B: It isn't really "beautiful". (or B: What are you talking about.)

It's not necessarily (although it could be, just not in this case) a sarcastic way of reacting to a compliment or statement, but rather them reacting in a way like A does not make sense by calling the photograph beautiful.

In your example's case, A asking about whether it's going to be very beneficial (I'm assuming financially, making B wealthy) makes B react by questioning what A is saying; as if B never had that aspect in mind when making the decision because it would turn out to not be all that beneficial.